# Using python in postgres and this error pops up

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

Getting this error:

```
Connection successful
Database Created Successfully
Connected to babynames database.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joseph/Desktop/INFO153 Final/Info153PartII.py", line 44, in <module>
    cur.execute('insert into boys values ({},{},{},{});'.format(row.tolist()[0],"'"+row.tolist()[1]+"'",row.tolist()[2],row.tolist()[3]))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

````
import pandas as pd

df_boys = pd.read_csv('babynames.txt', delimiter=' ',header=None, usecols=(0,1,2,3) )

df_boys.columns = ["Rank", "Name", "Total Babies", "Total Percentage"]

df_girls = pd.read_csv('babynames.txt', delimiter=' ',header=None, usecols=(0,4,5,6) )
df_girls.columns = ["Rank", "Name", "Total Babies", "Total Percentage"]

#check the imported data
df_boys.head()
df_girls.head()

#psycopg2 library for connecting to PostgreSQL database

import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user="postgres", password="postgres", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
conn.autocommit = True
print ("Connection successful")

#Create babynames database

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE babynames;')
print ("Database Created Successfully")

#connect to babynames database

conn_babynames = psycopg2.connect(database="babynames", user="postgres", password="postgres", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
conn_babynames.autocommit = True
print ("Connected to babynames database.")
cur = conn_babynames.cursor()

#create tables for boys and girls

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Boys (Rank integer, Name varchar(25), Total_Babies float, Total_Percentage float);')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Girls (Rank integer, Name varchar(25), Total_Babies float, Total_Percentage float);')

#import data from dataframe to table using insert into statement

for i, row in df_boys.iterrows():
    cur.execute('insert into boys values ({},{},{},{});'.format(row.tolist()[0],"'"+row.tolist()[1]+"'",row.tolist()[2],row.tolist()[3]))

for i, row in df_girls.iterrows():
    cur.execute('insert into girls values ({},{},{},{});'.format(row.tolist()[0],"'"+row.tolist()[1]+"'",row.tolist()[2],row.tolist()[3]))

#execute sql queries and display result of analysis

cur.execute("select sum(total) as t_children from ( select sum(Total_Babies) as total from boys union select sum(Total_Babies) as total from girls) as t")
total_babies=cur.fetchone()
print("Total babies born that year = ",total_babies[0])

cur.execute("select total from ( select sum(Total_Babies) as total from boys union select sum(Total_Babies) as total from girls) as t")
babies=cur.fetchall()
if (babies[0]>babies[1]):
    print("More boys were born in that year")
else:
    print("More girls were born in that year")

cur.execute("select name from boys where Total_Babies> {}".format(total_babies[0]/2))
babies=cur.fetchall()
print(babies)

cur.execute("select name from girls where Total_Babies> {}".format(total_babies[0]/2))
babies=cur.fetchall()
print(babies)```
````

Comment: Why are you working this way? Firstly, iterating the dataframe, which isn't needed and should generally be avoided if possible. Secondly, not using `to_sql` which pandas _could_ handle as a bulk insert and, **most importantly**, building queries with string formatting that leaves you open to SQL Injection, not to mention horrible syntax. I personally don't use `to_sql`, but then you should pull the data out as a nested list for a bulk insert. There's a _lot_ to unpack in answering this question

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to  build queries unless [you want your tables deleted by bobby tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is in `"'"+row.tolist()[1]+"'"` in your insert. As the error states, there's an issue trying to concatenate a float to a string. You should just be able to wrap the float in a `str()`, so all the concatenations (`+`) will be strings:

`"'"+str(row.tolist()[1])+"'"`

As some have pointed out, it is considered poor / dangerous practice to take strings from somewhere and concatenate them into your SQL queries. Malicious strings can wreck your database. My answer was for your question about why you got the error, but you would do well to look up parameterized SQL and how to implement using it with `psycopg2`

Comment: Oh please, no. Why are you encouraging string concatenation to build SQL queries? This just propagates the issue of SQL Injection, whether or not it's directly relevant with this dataset

Comment: The question asked was about an error, not about proper way to use prepared statements and avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I appreciate the advice bad practices.  I want to try to create this as is though to finish this out for practice.  I am now getting this error when I changed both formats, I'm so confused! Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\INFO153 Final\Info153PartII.py", line 44, in <module>
    cur.execute('insert into boys values ({},{},{},{});'.format(row.tolist()[0],"'"+str(row.tolist()[1])+"'",row.tolist()[2],row.tolist()[3]))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "michael" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into boys values (1,'nan',Michael,nan);

Comment: You need quotes around `Michael`, otherwise it interprets as a column reference rather than a string literal

Comment: I'm still having such issues.  The .txt this is trying to read from has a set up like this (this is the first row out of thousands):  1  Michael  462085  2.2506  Jessica  302962  1.5436

Comment: So it looks like you are trying to insert Michael in the 3rd column? But you are putting quotes around the second column, and inserting `'nan'` (with the quotes), but you should be putting those quotes around the 3rd argument, `'Michael'`. This thing: `"'"+str(row.tolist()[1])+"'"` should be done for the next argument `"'"+str(row.tolist()[2])+"'"`. If you *insist* on composing your SQL this way, I'd put the quotes in the first part of the statement: `'insert into boys values ({},{},"{}",{});`